# Database for increased scalability in a mmorpg?

Tags: mmo, databases, sql

I am planning a simple MMORPG, but even though it's a small, open source project, I'd like to have the best quality database. Which would be the best database software to use?

Examples:

**SQL** - MySQL, PostgreSQL, MSSQL ...

**NoSQL** - MongoDB, CouchDB ...

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2282/what-kind-of-databases-are-usually-used-in-an-mmorpg

Comment: No need to downvote this into oblivion, just close and redirect to the existing question.

Comment: @Hack: even when it's closed, it will be still downvotable.

Comment: "Simple" and "MMORPG" exclude each other. You might want to remove either of them.

Comment: @Lohoris it should be closed regardless, so that new answers, in case they add something substantially new, go into the old thread instead of splitting the effort, and so that no answers from the old thread just get copy-pasted to here. Downvoting means it's a bad question, but since the other, identical question was upvoted, that'd be paradoxical.

Comment: @Hack: I agree it has to be closed anyway, I was just pointing out that closing it won't make the downvotes stop, which I thought (perhaps incorrectly) you were implying.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL is free, is fast, can handle really big tables, is easy to use and you can find documentation and help extremely easy.

I also know MySQL better than say PostgreSQL and that is why I chose that one for my persistent multiplayer game.

Go with what you know best and if the worst case scenario happens (everyone wants to play your game and the DB knuckles) you can always change (or buy a faster server).

Comment: MySQL rocks. =P